# Trigger hook only by push into master

Tags: triggers, gitlab

I would like to trigger hook only when **master** being pushed. But in **Settings >> Integration** I see that triggers fire on any push into any branch:

[image: Trigger screen]

Can I configure it in Gitlab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done eg on Jenkins side in [Pipeline plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Plugin):

> Comma-separated list of source branches allowed to trigger a build
>   from a **Push event** or a **Merge Request event**. If both fields are left
>   empty, all branches are allowed to trigger this job. For **Merge Request**
>   **events** only the target branch name is filtered out by the include and
>   exclude lists.

[image]